# R: Plot predicted and actual response over a time variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis

I have a model where I would like to plot the prediction over a time variable. Adding the average response for that time point in the same graph would also be very helpful.

Here is some reproducible data.

```
set.seed(123)
x1 = rnorm(1000)           # some continuous variables 
x2 = rnorm(1000)
z = 1 + 2*x1 + 3*x2        # linear combination with a bias
pr = 1/(1+exp(-z))         # pass through an inv-logit function
 y = rbinom(1000,1,pr)      # bernoulli response variable

#valid glm:
df = data.frame(y=y,x1=x1,x2=x2,time=rep(seq(1:10),10))
fit = glm( y~x1+x2,data=df,family="binomial")
```

Now I would like to plot `mean(predict(fit,df,type="response"))` by the group `time` as well as `mean(y)` by the group `time`.

Any hints or ideas?

EDIT: Thank you for the responses! Yes I am aware that in this example time is not in the model. I just wanted to make an easy example. In my real model, time is included. And yes I want to plot the mean response and mean prediction over time.

Comment: There will be multiple predictions for each time value. Do you want to plot all of them?

Comment: Your model doesn't even appear to include time as a covariate.  The prediction won't depend on time. It's very unclear what you think the output should be here.

Comment: Valid points. I should have been more clear. I want the mean value for the response and prediction for each time point. In the real model the prediction does depend on time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like an odd thing to do, to me, without including time in the model. Below is one approach, calculating the mean of x and the mean of the prediction.

```
library(tidyverse)

df$pred <- predict(fit)

means <- df %>% 
  group_by(time) %>% 
  summarize(mean_y = mean(y),
            mean_pred = mean(pred)) %>% 
  gather(mean, val, -time)

ggplot(means, aes(time, val, color = mean)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect thank you! Yes I want to plot the mean of both over time. Sorry for not being specific about this. In the real model time is a very important variable so I want to look at predictions over time.

Answer (score 1):

You're predicting based on `x1` and `x2` not time, so there will be multiple predictions for each time. If you want to plot the `mean(y)` for each time and the mean predicted `y` for each time (in red) you can do

```
require(dplyr);require(reshape2);require(ggplot2)
df %>% 
    mutate(pred = predict(fit, df, type="response")) %>% 
    group_by(time) %>% 
    summarize_at(vars(y, pred), mean) %>% 
    melt(id = 'time') %>% 
    ggplot(aes(time, value, color = variable)) + geom_line()
```

Comment: Thank you! Agreed on all points. I was looking for the mean values over time for each.